# using json unit test files in a java program

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test some code. I have 2 fields  in my input data that may or may not be in the data, so I want to test all 4 scenarios (ab, a not b, b not a, neither a nor b). I created 4 different json files to use as mocked input, covering each scenario. I could have created one file with neither field, and then just added the required field into the mock data for each of the 4 tests. That approach to me, seems like the test has too much control over the test data. I prefer the 4 files approach, but one of my coworkers is complaining about 4 files being almost exactly the same.

I know this is asking for opinion, but which seems like a better approach? Have all 4 files, or have each test manipulate the data before the assertion?

Comment: It kinda depends. If the files are super big, then just one. If they are smaller, then it depends on if it takes longer to change a value, or add a value. 4 files will take longer to load though.

Comment: My vote is no files -- If this were me I'd want the test to just inject the json directly, so I don't have to keep the contents of the files in sync with my test over time.  I might consider using files if the data was really large.  If your class under test requires you provide a file, it's probably doing too much anyway, and should be split up.

Comment: Also consider cost of maintenance. If those two fields turn into four and you need to test all combinations, you have to supply 16 files.

Comment: my 4 files are fairly small (60 lines each)

Comment: 60 lines, not much of a problem either way won't make a difference. Completely arbitrary. Just different ways you'll have to code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like for me, your coworker is right.

Create two files: `a.json-part` and `b.json-part`. Let's `a.json-part` contains

```
"a": .....
```

and `b.json-part` contains similar content for `b` (NB: not a JSON, just a part!)

So, for your tests you can build test data by simple concatenation of parts like

```
String ab_json = "{" + readAsText("a.json-part") + "," + readAsText("b.json-part") + "}";
String a_not_b_json = "{" + readAsText("a.json-part") + "}";
```

and so on.

In this case you can combine your fields as you want and can be sure you didn't miss any file in case if some field is changed.